# How to use this type of array,struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have to do an exercise in C++ and I have a this kind of array-structure and I have never seen it before and I don't know how to use it, if someone can explain me please.

```
struct Fighter{
 string type;  // TIE Fighter, X-Wing, ...
 int velocity;
 int attack;    // attack power
 int shield;    // current shield status. 
 int cost;      // cost in credits};



 const Fighter FIGHTERTABLE[] = {
     { "TIE-Fighter",      150,  75, 30,  45 },
     { "TIE-Bomber",        80, 150, 45,  75 },
     { "TIE-Interceptor",  180,  65, 30,  55 },
     { "TIE-Advanced",     160,  80, 90,  95 },
     { "X-Wing",           175,  90, 75,  65 },
     { "Y-Wing",            90, 150, 90,  90 },
     { "A-Wing",           200,  60, 50,  45 },
     { "B-Wing",           120, 200, 90, 100 }
    };


const string FIGHTERABR[]= { "tf", "tb", "ti", "ta", 
                             "xw", "yw", "aw", "bw"
};
```

Comment: please post the code not print-screen

Comment: Don't post *pictures* of code, especially as links that can go stale. Instead copy the actual text into the body of the question. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And don't use unrelated language tags, if you are programming in C++ don't add the C tag.

Comment: As for your problem, you *have* used structures before? And you *have* used arrays before? Then just combine the knowledge you already have.

Comment: Just posted the code, sorry, and yes, I've used both of them but no clue.

Comment: You have an array where the elements are `Fighter` structures. What's the problem?

Comment: Think a little, how do you access a member of a structure? How do you access an element in an array? How do you *think* you would access a member of a structure, when that structure is an element in an array?

Comment: @molbdnilo: Probably not understanding the initialiser.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an initialized array of structure 'Fighter',
as to how would you use it or access values?
it will be same as normal array 
i.e.

```
string type = FIGHTERTABLE[0].type // type will be equal to "TIE-Fighter"
type =   FIGHTERTABLE[0].type     // now type will be equal to "TIE-Bomber"
```

exactly like a normal array, hope this clears things a bit.

Comment: I think i got it, im gonna try to use it and say you something, thanks you very much.

Comment: please accept the answer if it was helpful, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is an `array` of the type `Fighter`. So each element is a `Fighter` and is initialized using an `initializer list` `{std::string,int,int,int,int}`.
Read more about [initializer-list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)